# HDMI issue: Arzopa display shows "no input" other displays work fine

Tags: hdmi, display

I have a Raspberry Pi 5 running latest Pi OS (bookworm).
It works fine with a Viewsonic Omni portable display.
I unplugged the micro to mini HDMI cable from the Viewsonic and plugged it into an Arzopa A1S 14" (ie same cable). The Arzopa shows "no signal". Rebooting while plugged into the Arzopa shows same.
I've tried adding this section to /boot/firmware/config.txt and rebooting

```
[hdmi]
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
config_hdmi_boost=9
hdmi_group=1
```

No change. Viewsonic works fine. Switch to the Arzopa and I get nothing.
I used an HDMI (full size) to HDMI mini cable to connect the Arzopa display to another machine (Fedora, Asus PN50) and the display worked fine.
Any suggestions on the Pi/Arzopa issue?